# csrfp_token per request OR csrfp_token per session?

Tags: csrf

I m trying to prevent my website from CSRF attacks. I have tried multiple libraries which are already present in the market and finally found the best one https://github.com/mebjas/CSRF-Protector-PHP/. Fortunately, this has solved my problem but there was a twist when I've tested this with multitab as this is using csrfp_token change per request.

Is there any suggestion which can help me finding the security level difference between token per session and token per request?

And if token per request is the safest option then how to access it using multitab?

Answer (score 0):

CSRF should be per request. For each form  request there should be new csrf token generated and same should be send in form request.